# Elasticsearch: include specific facet values

Tags: elasticsearch, facet

elasticsearch provides parameter to exclude certain facets from facets values like this.

```
 "facets" : {
        "tag" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "tag",
                "exclude" : ["term1", "term2"]
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there any possibility to include certain facets?

I'm trying to get counts for facets that have been already selected by user along with global facets. E,g. you selected word *science* with count 20 (from autocomplete), i recompute facets to show other words that migh be selected, but the word *science* would not get to facet results since other words from global facets have count more than 400.

Is there any particular solution for this task?

Thanks for help

Comment: Can you perhaps do these as separate facets?  Less than ideal, I know...

Comment: @DaveS. thanks for suggestion, i thought about that and it will probably be the best workaround. thanks

Comment: @smolnar Did you give the script a try? May I know whether my answer was helpful?

Comment: i experimented with scripts, but actually, the better ways is to use to facets and combine their values yourself. by the way, there is a [project on github](https://github.com/imotov/elasticsearch-facet-script), that alows full custom script  support for facets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use scripting for that. The script will be run for each facet entry with the input variable `term` that contains the current value. The entry will be included or not on the final facet depending on the result of the script. If it returns false it will be excluded, otherwise it will be included.

```
"facets" : {
    "tag" : {
        "terms" : {
            "field" : "tag",
            "script" : "term == 'aaa' ? true : false"
        }
    }
}
```